# How to bundle an application for Linux?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, legacy

I am writing a C++ application, that uses Qt5.3. It uses WebSocket support from 5.3, so I can't build it with an earlier version. Also, it uses QT's WebKit support, so I can't build it statically.

This application has to support legacy distributions, like Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without Qt5.3 in the repositories.

How to make my application support distributions without Qt5.3?

Comment: Make some `.deb` (and perhaps `.rpm`) packages for your favorite distributions; perhaps also compile Qt5.3 into some package

Comment: I am making for Ubuntu 15.10+ because they have Qt5.4 in their repository. Qt is a dependency. But, older distributions don't have appropriate Qt in repositories. The question is: how to support legacy versions of Ubuntu, Debian, whatever..?

Comment: I would suggest to compile a recent Qt5 for all the distributions you want to support them, and package that Qt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good discussion of how to build out a Linux deployment package here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html.

I'd personally ship the shared libraries that I need and install them outside of the system `/usr/lib` space, and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to them instead. That way you know you're running it on a current version of Qt, and you've tested against it. The downside is depending on how many libraries you link against, you can end up with a fairly large deployment package.

Comment: Well, I have placed an application with Qt libraries into `/opt`. There was a problem on legacy Ubuntu distribution: the application didn't use system KDE style. It has just defaulted to its Fusion. Is there any way to make it use system style?

Comment: That's probably worth opening another question for to get more visibility.